# Extracting a factor from an Excel table by searching an input range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I am trying to extract a factor from an Excel table. The factor is based on a number of length ranges as shown in the attached example. Is it possible to use `HLOOKUP` or something similar to find the factor that corresponds to a input length?

For this example let's use an input length of 1200 [mm].

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you update your question to include what you've tried and where you're stuck? If you're just trying to figure out how to use `HLOOKUP`, [here's](https://support.microsoft.com/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f) the documentation.  See also "[ask]" and how to include a [mcve].  Reading the [tour] will earn you a badge too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `M2`:

```
=MAX(FILTER(B2:J2,--SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B1:J1,FIND("-",B1:J1&"-")-1),">","")<=M1))
```

Just for the sake of it, a little personal (unnecessary) exercise, this could be done with `FILTERXML()`:

```
=FILTERXML("<x>"&TEXTJOIN("</s></t>",,"<t>"&B2:J2&"<s>"&B1:J1&"-")&"</s></t></x>","//t[substring-before(translate(.//*,'>',''), '-')<="&M1&"][last()]")
```